# xcopy should not ask for folder (f) or directory (d):

Tags: xcopy

I have following script to copy one folder 'images' from E:\ drive to folder 'e_images' in d:\ drive path 'd:\D_IMAGES_BACKUP\e_images'. The source images folder including files, folders (directories) and sub-folder (sub directories). The problem is this when I execute the script it ask for folder (f) or directory (d):. Now I want that it should not ask for 'folder or directory'. Please tell me which option I will use to handle it. My script is:

```
@echo off
echo ******************************************************
echo Copying images files from E-Drive to D-Drive @ application server
echo ******************************************************


echo Copying files..........
echo *********************************

d:

cd d:\D_IMAGES_BACKUP\

rmdir /S /Q images


::SET COPYCMD=/Y
e:

xcopy E:\images\*.* /E /Y /D D:\D_IMAGES_BACKUP\IMAGES


exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
xcopy E:\images\*.* /E /Y /D D:\D_IMAGES_BACKUP\IMAGES\
```

Notice the trailing backslash.